# Show "my-choice.html" on index

Tags: .htaccess, indexing

How do I accomplish so when you go to "http://mysite.com" the file I want to show as index is with in the URL. Ex:

- You surf to: http://mysite.com
- What shows up in the browser URL field is: http://mysite.com/my-choice.html

As it is now "my-choice.html" doesn't show up. I have this in my .htaccess so far:

**DirectoryIndex my-site.html**

Comment: server platform details missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DirectoryIndex` directive only sets a list of files to try to resolve to when a request is for a directory. It won't redirect the browser like what you want. Try this instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /my-choice.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your lovely htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/?$ /my-choice.html [L,R=301]
```